# Place popup at top right corner of a window in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am developing an app for windows store using c#/xaml.

Xaml:

```
     <Popup x:Name="EditQuantityPopup"
           x:Uid="EditQuantityPopup"
           AutomationProperties.AutomationId="EditQuantityPopup"
           IsLightDismissEnabled="True"
           IsOpen="{Binding IsEditPopupOpened, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Grid x:Name="PopupPanel"
              Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
              Opacity=".9"
              Height="100"
              Width="230">


            <Grid x:Name="ContentPopupGrid"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Margin="20,0,10,15">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <!--<ColumnDefinition />-->
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"


                       Text="{Binding Text}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                       FontSize="15"
                       Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
                <ProgressRing Grid.Column="2" IsActive="{Binding LoadingData}" Height="75" Width="75"></ProgressRing>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
```

Code placing popout on top of a bottom app bar:

```
        private void EditQuantityPopup_Opened(object sender, object e)
    {
        int margin = 10;
        int appbarHeight = 90;
        EditQuantityPopup.HorizontalOffset = margin;
        EditQuantityPopup.VerticalOffset = Window.Current.CoreWindow.Bounds.Bottom - appbarHeight - PopupPanel.Height - margin;
    }
```

How to change code that popup should be placed at top right corner of a window?

Comment: Isn't this work - `<Popup Placement="Right"/>`?

Comment: I get the error:"The member "Placement" is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the layout type or types housing your PopUp element. Try this

```
EditQuantityPopup.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
EditQuantityPopup.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Top;
```

Additional to the above depending on your setup you may have to move the PopUp element to a new column in your Grid. eg

```
Grid.SetColumn(EditQuantityPopup, [your column number]);
```

If its in a Canvas you could use

```
var left = Window.Current.Bounds.Width - EditQuantityPopup.ActualWidth;
Canvas.SetLeft(EditQuantityPopup, left);
Canvas.SetTop(EditQuantityPopup, 0);
```

Hope that helps